# who are using gwt?

Tags: java, gwt, web

I start to learn 'gwt'. But i don't know how its important in software industry.

Any one can give me some famous website or web application applying google web toolkit?

Thanks.

Comment: [GWT Case Studies](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/casestudies/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google surely uses it :) [Here is a listing, from 2008 though.](http://www.gwtsite.com/whos-using-gwt/)  And [another listing from google](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/examples/) (we also used GWT for a client side component in a project)